# SOAP fault "DecryptAndDeserializeUserToken" on GetMetaData for Loket

Tags: soap

When I post the following to the web service of Loket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:svc="http://Loket.Webservice/ServiceContracts/2008/06">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <svc:GetMetaData>
            <svc:UserToken>TOKEN_RETRIEVED_WITH_LOGON</svc:UserToken>
        </svc:GetMetaData>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I receive an error:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="nl-NL">GetMetaData</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <DefaultFaultContract xmlns="http://Loket.Webservice/ServiceContracts/2008/06" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <ErrorMessage>DecryptAndDeserializeUserToken</ErrorMessage>
                </DefaultFaultContract>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. The user token is correct, which you can verify by calling the `List` method.

However, the as optional listed `DataIdentity` element is required. It must contain a hashed and encrypted value of the identity of a table, such as:

> MqhIh6BdOHPRi1s16c+fNUmm4TO1p7HTwEKxxjgiAjB+o12lO5fq1poK4OZcfOE0yZyvwkDjCcm17foDi7V0uqp06vfgTTv5/y8WyTBz+tPoxVdSOMECHARREMOVEDS4NQz3K8zogL

With this one present, it works. Please note that if you change the DataIdentity value a little, you will still receive a `DecryptAndDeserializeUserToken` error message.